# How to create an animated rounded progress bar with linear gradient?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, background-image, linear-gradients

I want to create something like this using CSS only.

[image: Rounded progress bar with gradient]

More specifically, I need a div that has x% yellow background with rounded edges. This yellow part can be at the start, at the end or anywhere in the middle like the image above. Rest of the div should be colored black.

I know that I can do this by placing a div inside another and setting the length, position and background-color of the inner div. But I want to know if it can be done using only one div by setting its background-color or background-image or something else. Using linear-gradient I was able to achieve all I wanted except the rounded edge of the yellow part. Here is the CSS:

```css
/* this will make the background-color 40% black, 20% yellow, 40% black */
div{
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        black 40%,
        yellow 20%,
        yellow 60,
        black 60%
    );
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And here is the code snippet:

```css
#mydiv{
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        rgb(20, 20, 20) 40%,
        rgb(255, 174, 0) 20%,
        rgb(255, 174, 0) 60%,
        rgb(20, 20, 20) 60%
   );
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Is it possible to achieve this using one div and CSS only?

I need to be able to control the length and position of the yellow part so that I can change its position and length in a CSS animation.

The animation will look like this:

```css
#outer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}

#inner{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 174, 0);
  animation: loading 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes loading{
  0%{
    left: -20%;
  }
  100%{
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does a pseudo element count as an extra element :)?

Comment: Doesn't the pseudo-element cause layout operations? The reason I want to do this using one div is, I don't want layout related operations in my animation (to make it smooth). But feel free to give the pseudo-element solution,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, it is needed to make the `yellow` bar as an independent selector.

And using `css`, you can use `:before` selector inside `#mydiv` tag and place the yellow bar there as follows.

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

#mydiv:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: I guess, the main approach is to be able to set position of that yellow "block" explicitly outside of CSS. So in this case this pseudo-element solution is not obviously flexible. But you can always use CSS variables to set the position :)

Comment: On the question, the yellow bar on black bar can be changed any time so it will be suitable to make it on independent selector so easy to customize later.

Comment: I tried to animate the position and length of the yellow part using your solution, but it's not working as expected. Can you add the animation, please? Here is the fiddle where I tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/oxwanegs/ @Derek.W

Comment: On `loading` keyframe, you have changed `left` and `width` attribute together. Just keep the `left` position to `0` because it represents the start point. And change the `width` attribute only from `0 ~ 100` and it will work as expected. - http://jsfiddle.net/06wqfp7m/ @SadmanRizwan

Comment: I updated my post. I want the animation look like the one I added in the post. @Derek.W

Comment: I have updated jsfiddle. Check again. http://jsfiddle.net/wmu5x7aL/. Using `overflow: hidden` on `#mydiv` style, you can hide the outer animation. @SadmanRizwan

Comment: It's almost perfect. The only problem is border-radius of the yellow part on the right side doesn't show perfectly during the animation. Can it be fixed? @Derek.W

Comment: It looks like this on the right side during the animation: https://imgur.com/FKePtOf @Derek.W

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222598/discussion-between-derek-w-and-sadman-rizwan).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a gradient only solution:

```css
.mydiv{
  --w:100px; /* width of progress*/
  --h:50px; /* height of the element*/

  height: var(--h);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:5px;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,orange 98%,transparent 100%) 0/var(--h) 100%,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,orange 98%,transparent 100%) 0/var(--h) 100%,
    linear-gradient(orange,orange) 0/ var(--w) 100%
    black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: var(--h);
  animation: a 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes a{
  from {
    background-position:
      left calc(-1*var(--w) - var(--h)) top 0,
      left calc(-1*var(--h)) top 0,
      left calc(-1*var(--h)/2 - var(--w)) top 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position:
      right calc(-1*var(--h)) top 0,
      right calc(-1*var(--w) - var(--h)) top 0,
      right calc(-1*var(--h)/2 - var(--w)) top 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"></div>

<div class="mydiv" style="--w:200px;--h:40px;"></div>

<div class="mydiv" style="--w:250px;--h:20px;"></div>
```

Or using pseudo element:

```css
.mydiv {
  --w:100px; /* width of progress*/
  --h:50px; /* height of the element*/
  
  height: var(--h);
  background: black;
  border-radius: var(--h);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:5px;
}

.mydiv::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--w);
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  animation: a 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes a {
  from {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"></div>

<div class="mydiv" style="--w:200px;--h:40px;"></div>

<div class="mydiv" style="--w:250px;--h:20px;"></div>
```

Comment: In the pseudo-element solution, radius on the right side doesn't look right during the animation. It happens in my given animation too. Any way to get rid of this?

Comment: The gradient solution works almost fine, but when I remove the alternate property of the animation to make it look like how I expected it to be, the yellow part resets its position from the end to start before completely going out of the black box. Is it possible to fix?

Comment: Also, I couldn't figure out how to control the width of the yellow part in the gradient solution.

Comment: Is it possible to set the width of the yellow part using percentage (like 20% of the whole width) instead of using pixel? @Temani Afif

Comment: @SadmanRizwan only using the second solution (pseudo element) the first one works only with pixel

Comment: Then, maybe I have to use pseudo-element or an inner div. Because the width of the whole div is not fixed in my case, the width percentage of the yellow part is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible gradient solution

Just add round caps at the start and end of your linear gradient with `radial-gradient`

```css
#mydiv{
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        transparent 25px,
        rgb(255, 174, 0) 25px,
        rgb(255, 174, 0) calc(100% - 25px),
        transparent calc(100% - 25px)
   ), 
    radial-gradient(circle at 25px, rgb(255, 174, 0) 25px, transparent 25px),
    radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 25px), rgb(255, 174, 0) 25px, transparent 25px);
   background-size: 50% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border-radius: 25px;
   
   animation: moving 3s infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes moving {
  100% { 
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: How can I achieve the animation like the one I added in the post using radial-gradient? Can you add an animation example please? @Limbo

Comment: @SadmanRizwan I have updated my answer. Note that I have also changed a little gradient definition